# Cannot rename package in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have not troubles with renaming packages in idea, but... I have "example" package and I want to rename it to "enum", but Idea does not allow me to do that. When I create a new package "enum", it warns me, that I will not be able to create any java classes within. What is the problem???

Comment: Is your package in the sources root package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot rename the package to `enum`, because it is a reserved keyword in Java.

At the Oracle tutorial page "[Naming a package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)" it says

> In some cases, the internet domain name may not be a valid package name. This can occur if the domain name contains a hyphen or other special character, if the package name begins with a digit or other character that is illegal to use as the beginning of a Java name, **or if the package name contains a reserved Java keyword, such as "int"**.

Comment: Good catch! Completely blanked on this one. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought that it is not applied to packages!

Comment: I was a bit surprised myself :)